# How I am able to access the enum value just by reference, where reference itself is null?

Tags: java, enums

I have this following code:

```
enum Animals{
    DOG("woof"), CAT("meow"), FISH("burble");
    String sound;
    Animals(String s){ sound = s; }
}

class TestEnum{
    static Animals a;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(a + "   " +a.DOG);
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
null   DOG
```

I don't understand how I am able to access a.Dog where value of a is null. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: You haven't initialized the enum value `a`.  Think of `a` as a static reference to all values inside the enum.

Comment: but why I am getting value for a.DOG?

Comment: Because DOG is `static`

Comment: 'a' is just a reference without any object assigned to it

Comment: The enum values are static fields in the `Animals` class. You can always access a static field or method "with" a null reference to the containing class.

Comment: Accessing a static field (here `DOG`) through an instance reference (here `a`)  is poor style. Exactly because of the confusion it leads to in your case (among other reasons). Instead use `Animals.DOG`, and no confusion is possible.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner , It make sense now. I missed this rule.